# Error rendering React component with Promise

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am facing an issue while rendering a React component in my application. I receive the following error: "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

I believe the problem is related to the use of Promises when retrieving cookies during the initial rendering process (`getInitialProps`). I made some modifications, but the error persists.

```
import Cookies from 'cookies';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import LoginPage from '../components/login';
import HomePage from '../components/home';

function Index({ auth, error }) {
    console.log(auth)
   if (auth) {
        return <HomePage />;
    } else {
        return <LoginPage error={error} />;
    }
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res, query }) {
    const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);
    let auth = null;

    try {
        auth = cookies.get('auth') || null;

        if (auth && !(await checkToken(auth))) {
            auth = null;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting auth cookie:', error);
        auth = null;
    }

    return {
        props: {
            auth,
            error: query.error || null,
        },
    };
}

async function checkToken(token) {
    try {
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        return !!verified;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error verifying token:', e);
        return false;
    }
}

export default Index;
```

Login API

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).end();
}

const cookies = Cookies(req, res);
const body = req.body;

const login = await checkLogin(body);

if (login.success) {
    const expires = new Date().getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);
    const token = jwt.sign({
        time: Date.now(),
        username: body.username
    }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    cookies.set('auth', token, {
        expires: new Date(expires),
    });
    res.redirect("/")
} else
    res.redirect("/?error=" + login.msg);
```

}

I tried make this, but I had no results:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res, query }) {
    const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);
    let auth = null;

    try {
        auth = cookies.get('auth') || null;

        if (auth && !(await checkToken(auth))) {
            auth = null;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting auth cookie:', error);
        auth = null;
    }

    return {
        props: {
            auth,
            error: query.error || null,
        },
    };
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you have the 2 imports commented out?

Comment: No, a server side process does not affect directly your rendering part. It just sends a json to a page component. Please share your `jsx` part.

Comment: @ZombieChowder
No, it's only to show that I imported

Comment: @i2i3 Ok, I go edit the post

Comment: @VGAPP  Either `<HomePage />` or `<LoginPage error={error} />` likely has a problem. Please share them also.

Comment: @i2i3 the pages HomePage and LoginPage, it's only HTML returning. But have the API to make login. I go to add in the question

Comment: @VGAPP I want to distinguish problems. If you don't use `<HomePage />` and `<LoginPage error={error} />` , it works without errors?  Just try replacing them with `<div/>` and check it goes well. If it doesn't hit errors, your custom components have a problem, but hit errros, as you said the server side process has a problem.